# The easiest and fastest way to enable an Android app to graph data

Tags: android, graph, statistics

I am making an app that has to display some statistical data in a graph. I am at the stage now where I can extract data, and now I have to graph the data. Can anybody direct me to a tutorial which would teach me how to do it from A to Z in detail?

Looking forward to hear from anybody soon!

Comment: how bout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android?rq=1

Comment: I appreciate that but unfortunately I am just a beginner and what I need is an example that I can run on a PC and examine the code in Eclipse so I can understand how it works and learn.